# Windows Services on Azure Virtual Machines with Availability Sets

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-availability-set

I have few (around 10) Windows Services on my existing environment. We are planning to migrate to Azure with the following.

1. Host our database on Azure SQL Database.
2. Install all the 10 Windows Services in a Azure Virtual Machine. Please note that these Windows Services does bulk inserts into the Azure SQL databases.
3. Take 2 instances of VM (specified in #2 above) and configure them in an Availability Set to avail the SLA.

I have two questions.

1. Do I need to install all my 10 Services to both the VMs?
2. Will that NOT be reduntant running the Windows Services in both the VMs? So, the Bulk Inserts will be duplicated to the Azure SQL Databases.

Please let me know if I am thinking in the right direction or are there any alternate methods (like Worker Roles) of utilizing the existing Windows Services on Azure with minimum or no changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, I got an answer to my question. When there are two VMs in a given Availability Set, ONLY one will be up and running. The other VM will come into picture only when the primary VM is down.

Thanks,
Prawin

Answer (score 0):

If you are to take advantage of Azures SLA you will need to have at least 2 VM's (from within the same family) in an availability set.  The SLA covers the VM's in the availability set NOT what you are running on the OS.  For example if you have all services running on one instance and that box goes down, you lose those services till the box recycles.  Microsoft is still covered on their SLA because at least one of the VM's in the availability set is available.